# How much space is needed to feed 30,000 people?

Tags: technology, food, gas-giants, infrastructure

also how much space is needed for 30,000 people? I need to build an orbiter that will feed and make sure 30,000 people survive on Jupiter.

Comment: 3 times as much space as needed to [feed 10,000 people](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25800/how-large-would-a-space-ship-need-to-be-to-feed-10-000-people)

Comment: People do not survive on Jupiter, it has no surface you can walk on. It might have one your dead body can fall on after you die because the extreme pressure turned you into a peanut. :)

Comment: @Separatrix, that should have been an answer I guess...

Comment: People, comment your close vote reasons! This is especially important for new users that don't know how the site works.

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of the above linked question about feeding 10,000 people. However, that question doesn't have great answers in the first place so I threw an edit on it to push it to the top of the queue and hopefully get it a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

They probably won't all eat at the same time, since you'll have people working in shifts.

[Reception venues recommend](http://www.entertaining.bestyoucanget.com/squarefootage) 10 to 15 square feet per person. So around 27,870 m2 to seat them all at once.

If you have three shifts then you can divide that by three: 10,000 m2

You can break those shifts up into seating times, allowing 45-60 minutes for each meal to sit, be served, eat and clean up afterwards. This would give you around 24 seating times total. But each shift needs three meals, so that's 8 seating times per shift. Space needed: 1250 m2