# How much land would it take to feed 1,000,000,000,000 people?

Tags: food, agriculture

In my world , the Pan-Human Empire finally boasts a total area of 10,000,000,000 miles , and a population of 800 billion. They are "only" 200 billion people left to be born until the empire finally reaches its goal of 1 trillion people. Due to this , the government begins to survey land for Allocation to its state run Agricultural sector.

***Possibly useful information***

- do to the infinite plane world ( upon which my story occurs ) having a similar sea to land ratio as earth , only 2.5 billion of its total area is actually land
- 1/3 , or 834 million miles of this land is desert , leaving 1.666 billion miles of non-dessert
- 1/10 , or 166.6 million miles of This are national parks , leaving 1.5 miles of non-park land
- 1/20 or 75 million miles of this is urbanized city/town/village land , leaving 1.425 billion miles of farmable land
- 1/10 or 142.5 million miles of this is either reservation land or privately owned land , leaving 1.2825 billion miles of land that can be used by the government to farm

My Questions are:

A) How much would it take to feed 1 trillion people who eat , stay , 1200 pounds each per year? ( assume that only plants are being grown )

B) Is the available amount of land enough to feed the trillion people?

C) if the amount is not enough , how much more land would the government have to annex to obtain enough land?

Comment: Actually not that much really. Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAJeYe-abUA

Comment: @Thucydides thats a 37 minute video! summarise it!

Comment: @Cursed1701 it is already summarisation of possibilities. Short speaking have energy and technology and  U may feed few million people per 1km^3 of volume of food production facility or even more.

Comment: I don't think these are duplicates. Linked one asks for **farmland**. This one apparently also allows other methods, like **aeroponics**. Similar, but not duplicates for me.

Comment: THis question is much too broad.  What technology can be applied?  Can multi-story industrial greenhouses be employed?  What is the impact of fishing and other aquaculture?  Is the society predominantly vegitarian?  The funny thing about Earth is that no matter how often or how loud people complain about the inability of the planet to sustain our growing population, we keep coming up with ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An acre per person is the general guideline, but you might be able to squeeze that to as low as a quarter acre with fertile soil, a good climate, and intensive scientific farming techniques.

There are 640 acres per square mile, so you have 820 billion acres available. That's only a bit less than an acre per person, so I think you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

[Using this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/how-many-people-can-you-feed-per-square-kilometer-of-farmland/9601#9601) as a reference:
One km<sup>3</sup> of aeroponics bays can feed can potentially feed 49,210,000 people on sweet potatoes at 2k calories per person per day, from there its simple mathematics: 1 trillion / 49.2 million = km<sup>3</sup> of aeroponics bays needed, which equals 20,321.07 km<sup>^3</sup> of aeroponics bays.

But if they don't like sweet potatoes then you have an issue.

Comment: I've always loved the idea of 100 story hydroponic buildings covering an acre of land. Then you grow 100 acres of food on 1 acre of land. Not very practical or cost effective, but still an enjoyable thought.

Comment: Sun only shines on the top floor, so how does that work?

Comment: One sweet potato gives you about 6000 micrograms of vitamin A. Thats great, it is about 5x as much as you need per day, but also its enough to poison you. Have you ever seen a culture that uses sweet potatoes (not Yams, which are different) as a staple food? There aren't any. Thats because if your mom eats three sweet potatoes a day, every day, she'll kill you before you are done breast feeding.

Comment: @kingledion i did some basic research, for a male adult of age 17+, they can take 3000 micro grams per day, and a single sweet potato is 368% of what you should get in a day, not your 500%, but still a considerable amount more, so yes it would slowly kill you, but i was thinking about calories rather than diet

Comment: @JDługosz sorry for late response! you put in a bunch of UV lights on each floor

Comment: @kingledion I've heard Okinawa is famous for it's sweet potato consumption. How do they evade vitamin A overdose, maybe you know?

Comment: @aleck First, there are two different 'yams' in Okinawa, a purple variant of _Ipomea batatas_ which is a true sweet potato, and a different purple yam _Dioscorea_alata_. I'm not sure how much of either is eaten, and I can't find vitamin A content for that yam. Second, a sweet potato's vitamin A comes ~90% from [beta carotene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-Carotene), which is responsible for the orange color (also, the color in carrots, mangoes, pumpkin, etc). If the sweet potato is no longer orange, it probably doesn't have the same amount of vitamin A.

Comment: @kingledion thanks mate! apparently it's purple one that is eaten there.